# Pandas merge: combining column values & merging new column values to the same row

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm uncertain whether one method, or even the practice of merging dataframes, can achieve my intentions below- or whether I need to resort to writing my own functions using for loops.

I want to progressively build up a master dataframe comprising all possible column values from a number of smaller dataframes with variable column data. All the dataframes come from records with the same name convention and duplication of rows with the same name should be avoided

- I want to successively merge each smaller dataframe into the master
- No data should be lost. Where names are shared, values should be combined into the master dataframe's existing columns
- No new columns should be created
- If two smaller dataframes have different values in the same column I would like those values to share the same column in the master, list or string doesn't matter
- When a smaller dataframe entry of the same name contains new values for previously unfilled columns they should be merged into existing rows rather than creating new rows

## 1. My dataframes

```
df_master = pd.DataFrame(columns=('Names','Age','Hair','Breakfast','Lunch','Dinner'))
df_lunch = pd.DataFrame([['Joe',16,'red','sandwich'],['Mary',22,'brown','carrot']],columns=('Names','Age','Hair','Lunch'))
df_ingredients =  pd.DataFrame([['Joe','ham']],columns=('Names','Lunch',))
df_breakfast = pd.DataFrame([['Joe','fruit loops'],['Mary','toast']],columns=('Names','Breakfast',))
```

## 2. Attempt to progressively build up the master dataframe

```
df_master = pd.merge(df_master, df_lunch, on=['Names','Age','Hair','Lunch'], how='outer')
```

so far, so good (except the column order goes funny)

```
df_master = pd.merge(df_master, df_ingredients, on=['Names','Lunch'], how='outer')
```

joe has been given a new row, his ham hasn't been added to his sandwich

```
df_master = pd.merge(df_master, df_breakfast, on=['Names','Breakfast'], how='outer')
```

joe and mary have new rows, just to accommodate breakfast

## 3. How it should ideally look by this stage

```
df_base = pd.DataFrame(columns=('Names','Age','Hair','Breakfast','Lunch','Dinner'))
df_sofar = pd.DataFrame([['Joe',16,'red','fruit loops', 'sandwich, ham'],['Mary',22,'brown','toast','carrot']],columns=('Names','Age','Hair','Breakfast','Lunch'))
df_ideal = pd.merge(df_base, df_sofar, on=['Names','Age','Hair','Breakfast','Lunch'], how='outer')
```

shows how I'd like the final dataframe from 2. to look

```
    Dinner  Names   Age Hair    Breakfast   Lunch
0           Joe     16  red     fruit loops sandwich, ham
1           Mary    22  brown   toast       carrot
```

Am I going about this all wrong? Or is there something obvious I'm missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try `concat` + `groupby` + `agg`:

```
df = pd.concat(
    [df_master, df_lunch, df_ingredients, df_breakfast]
)

g = df.groupby('Names', sort=False, as_index=False).agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()))
g['Age'] = df_lunch['Age']

  Names    Breakfast Dinner   Hair         Lunch  Age
0   Joe  fruit loops           red  sandwich,ham   16
1  Mary        toast         brown        carrot   22
```

**An Alternative**
If you cast everything to string, you lose no information during the `groupby`:

```
df = pd.concat(
        [df_master, df_lunch, df_ingredients, df_breakfast]
    )

df.groupby('Names', sort=False, as_index=False).agg(
        lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str))
)

  Names   Age    Breakfast Dinner   Hair         Lunch
0   Joe  16.0  fruit loops           red  sandwich,ham
1  Mary  22.0        toast         brown        carrot
```

Comment: Did you find out why `agg` drops `Age`?

Comment: I'm trying to figure that out too- it also drops the empty column 'Dinner'

Comment: @jaumebonet Because str.join will not work for integers, pandas just drops the invalid dtype completely.

Comment: @JeffS. Sorry about that, I forgot to account for `df_master`. Check again.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, you are right... that's... unfortunate. but then there is the option to cast, it seems.

Comment: Perfect, casting to string plays well with an expanded master that will have additional number columns. Thanks for your help, this has been frustrating me all morning!